# List index out of range after using shuffle function in Python

Tags: python

It is important to let the readers know that I sometimes have to delete items in my list of lists before calling the function.

### Error Code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\permdebunk.py", line 195, in <module>
    shuff(c,len(c))
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\permdebunk.py", line 181, in shuff
    c[i],c[j] = c[j],c[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Python's `random.shuffle()` is insufficient for my needs if it will not perform all possible permutations. So I did some google searching and found this function that shuffles a list that supposedly circumvents the problems stated above about Python's `random.shuffle()`

```
def shuff(c, n):
    for i in range(n-1,0,-1):
        random.seed()
        j = random.randint(0,i+1)
        c[i],c[j] = c[j],c[i]
```

The problem seems to occur after I append `c[0]` to `c` and then del `c[0]` to push into the list.  [I have over 200+ lines of code as an experiment into an NP hard problem.](https://hackaday.io/project/173227/logs)Please look at the first log in the link. And remember to check line 195 and 181

Edit: The link didn't have line numbers so use **ctrl + f** to find the word shuff

### Question

What ways can I "push" into the list without getting any index errors? And, why does python throw that error?

Comment: Just an aside: if you seed your random numbers every time, they won't be very random.

Comment: @MarkRansom I am using a Quantum Random Number Generator.

Comment: `randint` includes both endpoints. And you are starting from `n-1` - so `n` can also be generated there

Comment: What problem exactly are you trying to solve by reinventing the `shuffle` wheel?  While there are theoretically limitations on the randomness of shuffling, it's not clear to me that your implementation addresses them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`random.randint()` includes both endpoints. So when `i = n - 1`, `randint(0, i + 1)` could return `(n - 1) + 1`, which is `n`.  `c[n]` is out of range of the list.

I should think changing the `randint()` call to `randint(0, i)` should work.

Comment: so if n is > len(c) I could create an if statement in the function that can redefine n. Ok, lets do this!

Comment: Great, I should change randint(0, i) or maybe I can append c[len(c)-1]) and then do shuff(c, len(c)-1)?? hmm.